How to split my incoming internet across rooms using the same cable for the internet and the local network?
I’m trying to connect a few rooms in my house to the local Ethernet network. The current setup is confusing me as I’ve not had a similar one in the past.
My current setup is on the left with only one cable actually connected and my goal is the one on the right.
Basically I currently have a utility panel that has one incoming Ethernet cable that goes to the internet provider and 4 Ethernet cables going out into the rooms. The incoming cable is hardwired to the living room Ethernet cable essentially making it one cable and the only live Ethernet socket in my home.
That cable is currently connected to a TPLink mesh router that acts as the gateway and my wireless access point for the house.
My goal is to add more mesh access points to every room and to have them connect to each other via Ethernet.
If I’d plug the incoming internet cable into a switch on port 1 and the rest of the room cables to the other ports could I still get my router to connect to the internet and also and provide access to all the other APs back through the same cable through the switch?
I’m asking here instead of just trying it because it would be very hard to actually set up in the current environment since there’s no easily accessible power in there and I don’t want to mess up the existing cabling if this is a bad idea in the first place. Thanks for any thoughts



If I’d plug the incoming internet cable into a switch on port 1 and the rest of the room cables to the other ports could I still get my router to connect to the internet and also and provide access to all the other APs back through the same cable through the switch?

With a plain switch, don't do that – it might technically work, but would result in the same segment having both your ISP's DHCP service and your LAN router's DHCP, which is a bad idea. (It might lead to your PCs picking up public IP addresses directly from the ISP, or it might lead to your neighbor's router picking up your LAN IP address...)
It's possible to do this properly using 802.1Q VLANs, which let the same cable carry logically separate networks by tagging each packet with a VLAN ID. You need a VLAN-capable switch at the utility box, and another one (or a VLAN-capable router) where the modem is.
Then you'll be able to designate one port on each switch for the WAN connection (uplink cable to VLAN 2, and VLAN 2 to the router's "WAN" port), one port for the trunk connection between switches (both VLAN IDs set to tagged), and the remaining ports for your LAN, without having one network's packets leak to the other.
(For example, TP-Link's popular TL-SG10x "web managed" switches might work, though they have some annoying problems of their own – e.g. better not set them to use DHCP when VLANs are in use... – but I've used them when I needed something small enough to fit in a box.)
A router with built-in VLAN support could avoid the need for the second switch, but most home Wi-Fi routers can't do that, at least not on a single port, so it'll be easier to have two switches instead.

The easiest way to do this, is to have a cable from your Modem and AP run back to the utility box, and put a switch there also.
From the utilitybox, that cable just only goes to the modem, and another cable from the modem goes back to the utility box and into a switch to distribute it to the rest of the rooms.
Alternatively, move the Modem and AP to the utilitybox, then you don't have to use a 2nd cable.
